# Image dimensions in material-ui-dropzone

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-ui-dropzone in a website to get multiple images which gives a set of props. But, I want to work with dimensions of the images.

But, dimensions of image is not provided in those props.

Is there a way to get the dimensions of the image through [material-ui-dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-dropzone) ?

This is imported Component from material-ui-dropzone. Which gives an array of images with size prop but not the dimension prop.

```
<DropzoneAreaBase
    dropzoneClass={classes.root}
    dropzoneText="Drag and Drop Images Here or Click"
    acceptedFiles={["image/jpeg", "image/png"]}
    showPreviews={false}
    filesLimit={1000}
    maxFileSize={10000000000}
    onDrop={(files) => ctx.imgDropSelectHandler(files)}
    onChange={(files) => console.log("Files:", files)}
    onAlert={(message, variant) => console.log(`${variant}: ${message}`)}
    // getFileAddedMessage={(files) => alertMessageHandler(files)}
/>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Actually, I'm new so i don't know whether this count as minimal reproducible example. But, I've updated it.

Comment: In this case a reproducible example would be a stack snippet or a codesandbox. But maybe someone who has enough experience with this component can answer this without one